# jQuery: Selecting specific input hidden element (by index) in an array of input hiddens

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors, hidden-field

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><td>...</td><td><input type="hidden" name="price[1]" value="10"></td><td>...</td>
<tr><td>...</td><td><input type="hidden" name="price[6]" value="230"></td><td>...</td>
<tr><td>...</td><td><input type="hidden" name="price[7]" value="40"></td><td>...</td>
<tr><td>...</td><td><input type="hidden" name="price[10]" value="10"></td><td>...</td>
</table>
```

I have also got that this is important to say that they are stored in `table` `td`s and it's preferred not to bring them out of the table. **(So I updated the code to be more like in real)**

What I want, is a way to **select one of them by their `index()` number** to be able to get their `val()`.

I know that their `index` is counted from `0` to `3`. I want to get the `val()` of the second one with `index(1)`.

Comment: You want to select one of them (which one?) or all of them? What do you want to do with the values?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the value of the second hidden input:

```
$('input[type=hidden]:eq(1)').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery it would be:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/32NU8/

Answer (score 1):

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/yGCP2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was not clear enough. Any I appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/brXn4/)

```
var a="";
$("input[type=hidden]" ).each(function( index ) {
    a+=($(this).val()) + ",";

});
alert(a);
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was not clear enough. Any I appreciated your help.